# How do a use addition operations using a linked list using _getch() function ? C++

Tags: c++

So I need help with making a linked list use math operations, it currently only does the '+' operation and I do need it to work for all operations.

My current problem with the code is the '+' operation. I don't know who to remove it from the string as it can't be used in the stod function. So pretty much I need help removing the '+' from the linked list and once the = is inputted, the result will be produced.

Thank you for the help in advance.

I'll provide my current code and current output and desired output.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    std::string data{};
    Node* next{ nullptr };
};



void calculator(Node*& head, Node*& tail) {
    bool quit{ false };
    std::string temp{};
    Node* current{ nullptr };
    char c = ' ';

    int i = 0;

    map<int, string> map1 = {};


    while (c != 'e')
    {
        char c = ' ';
        c = _getch();


        if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == ' ') continue;

        if (c == ';') {
            cout << "Returning To Program Menu" << endl;
            return;
        }


        temp = temp + c;

        current = new Node;
        current->data = temp;

        if (tail) {

            tail->next = current;
            tail = current;
        }
        else {
            head = current;
            tail = current;
        }

        std::stringstream ss;
        for (current = head; current; current = current->next) {
            ss << current->data;
        }


        std::cout << "+------------+" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "|" << std::setw(12) << ss.str() << "|" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "+------------+" << std::endl << std::endl;
        temp = "";

        if (c == '+')
        {
            map1[i] = ss.str();
            i++;
            current = new Node;


        }

        if (c == '=')
        {
            double x = stod(map1[0]);

            double y = stod(map1[1]);

            double plus = x + y;

            cout << plus << endl;

            cout << "Program Over" << endl;

            return;
            

        }
    }


}





int main() {
    bool quit = false;
    int choice = 0;
    Node* head = nullptr;
    Node* tail = nullptr;

    calculator(head, tail);


    for (auto tmp{ head }; tmp;) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
        delete head;
        head = tmp;
    }
}
```

Current Output:

```
+------------+
|           2|
+------------+

+------------+
|          2+|
+------------+

+------------+
|         2+3|
+------------+

+------------+
|        2+3=|
+------------+
```

Then error due to '+' being in the list:
[image]

Desired Output:

```
+------------+
|           2|
+------------+

+------------+
|          2+|
+------------+

+------------+
|         2+3|
+------------+

+------------+
|        2+3=|
+------------+

5
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not why its failing, its failing because 'map1[1]' is empty

You seem to think that 'map1' has the numbers in it, it does not, you only write to it when you hit a '+

```
    if (c == '+')
    {
        map1[i] = ss.str();
        i++;
        current = new Node;


    }
```

so map1[1] is empty for '2+3='

I am sure this should be

```
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        map1[i] = ss.str();
        i++;
        current = new Node;


    }
```

altough this will not work with multi digit numbers

plus this is also wrong

```
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        map1[i] = ss.str(); <<<=== display striing with 2+3 in it
        i++;
        current = new Node;


    }
```

this is why you were getting + in your numbers
should be

```
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        map1[i] = temp; <<<== current char as string
        i++;
        current = new Node;


    }
    temp = ""; <<<== move here
```

Comment: How would I get this to work with multi-digit numbers